# Excel function: How to find a total of a number based on another cell value

Tags: excel, function

I have a problem in excel sheet, please help me to over come this problem.
problem is below.
I need to get a total of sum numbers  in different cell based on another cell. I will explain more. 
in my first column contains three types like(car, bike,bus) I need to get total number of bus, car, bike seperatly in different column.

attached the sample data. please check the sheet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD9kP.jpg)

Thanks,
Nihdin Joseph

Comment: Explore the SUMIF() function. I think that's all you need.

Comment: can you please give me a sample.

Comment: @aadhi https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: Thank you bro. I got it. =SUMIF(D8:D46,"CAR",F8:F46). =SUMIF(D8:D46,"BUS",F8:F46). =SUMIF(D8:D46,"TWO WHEELER",F8:F46)

Answer (score 0):

If your Vehicle Type is B5 through B25 and your Vehicle Count is C5 through C25, this will Count all the cars:

```
=SUMIF(B5:B25,"=CAR",C5:C25)
```